# Execute simple mysqli query on click with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

My AJAX/Java knowledge is very limited so this might sound like a stupid and very easy question, but here I go.

I am trying to execute a very simple one line mysqli query after clicking a link on a php page. This query has to be executed in the background, so without reloading the page, so I would need AJAX to do that.

**EDIT:** This is the code I have now.

The PHP page (notes_checked.php) with my query:

```
if ($user_ok == true) {
        mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE users SET notescheck=now() WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1");} 
 else {
    exit();
}
```

The Javascript function I execute when clicking:

```
<script>

function notesChecked() {

  document.getElementById("notbadge").style.background = "#B0B0B0";
  document.getElementById("notbadge").innerHTML = "0";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'php_includes/notes_checked.php',
    data: data,//post data
    success: function()
    {
     alert("You just checked your notes!");
    }
});

}


</script>
```

The link on my main page:

```
<a onclick="notesChecked()">Checked</a>
```

So this script sets the counter back at 0 and changes the background color of the span when the user clicks on it. Now I have to execute the mysqli query so this number stays 0 when the user refreshed the page or comes back later.

Anyone who can tell me if there's an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Oh and also SO is **not a free coding service** We are more than willing to help with code that you have a probelms with, but we dont write code from a spec

Comment: in case you use jquery: $.ajax({ url: "linktomysqlline.php"});

Comment: I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create another php file for the mysql query to execute(Example:- yourquery.php) which will execute in the background.

Then put an AJAX call to the file :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "yourquery.php",
  success: function(response) {
     // show response for success
   }
});
```

Comment: I just edited the question with the code I have now, but it's still not working strange enough

Comment: I am getting no response at all.. The function noteschecked() executes the first two lines, but the other code just won't execute. Where can I possibly see the errors?

Comment: I just looked at the Network tap in Google Chrome after pressing F12 to see if my ajax calls were being made. After clicking the button, I could see the ajax call was made to my php file.
`Request URL:xxx/php_includes/mark_as_read.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK`

So what else could be the problem then?

Comment: You could use beforeSend in the ajax code to check if the ajax is working or not.Just put it before the success.
beforeSend: function() {
// alert something
}.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#buttionid').click(function(){
     postajax();
   });
});

function postajax()
{
//When the button is clicked do this
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'yourlinktomysql.php',
    data: data,//post data
    success: function()
    {
     //do something if the ajax-action is a success
    }
});
}
```

Comment: You should have appended it to the question then. What is the error that you are getting? I'mean in your browser console

Comment: I just edited my question with what I have now. I am not getting any error messages, just nothing happens. Even when I put an echo in my php file I want to execute to test it, I get nothing. It looks like it just does not want to execute the php script at all

Comment: Is the event getting triggered? Have you checked your js by putting breakpoints

Comment: When I click the button the first few lines of my script execute (changing the color and the html text), it's just the ajax code that does not want to work..

Comment: Still not working. I've put my other lines in the script (`document.getElementById("notbadge").style.background = "#B0B0B0";`) and they execute without problems, only the ajax does not want to work. I've noticed it in another php script I have too that it does not want to work. So strange

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can write:

HTML

```
<button class="i-like-trains">DO YOU LIKE TRAINS?</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.i-like-trains').on('click', function(){
    var name = 'BOB';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'myphpdoc.php',
        data: { 'name' : name },
        success: function()
        {
          alert(msg); // alerts the response from myphpdoc.php
        }
    });
  });
});
```

MYPHPDOC.PHP

```
<?php
    // create $db_connection //

    $name = $_POST['name']; // post variable has the same name as in the ajax data array

    mysqli_query($db_connection, "UPDATE users SET notescheck = now() WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1");

    echo 'YES, YOU LIKE TRAINS TOO <3'; // example response
?>
```

hope I helped :-)

Comment: I tried all of this but it's just not working :( My main php file has `<a class="notbutton">Check</a>` on it, my php file with mysqli query is the same as you posted and my script too, and it's still not working..