# Creating a favourites page

Tags: php, sql

I currently have a 3 tables setup in PHPMYADMIN

Customer(CUSTOMER_ID,........)
Product(PRODUCTID, ProductName..............)
Favourite(PRODUCTID, CUSTOMER_ID)

The Products page currently displays all items stored in the database like:

```
echo '<table border=1>';
        echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th><th>Favourite</th>';
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<tr><td>'.$row['ProductName'].'</td><td>'.$row['Category'].'</td><td>'.$row['ProductDescription'].'</td><td>'.$row['ProductPrice'].'</td><td><img src="../images/'.$row['ProductImageName'].'" /></td><td>FAVOURITE</td>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

This all displays correctly. What I need is when the user clicks the favourite button it adds their ID and the ProductID to the database so that when they go to the favourite.php page it displays all their favourited items which an option to remove the favourited item.

The problem I am having is getting the query to run. Here is what  I currently have.

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';
session_start();

$customerID = $_SESSION['cust'];
$product = $row['ProductName'];


//echo $customerID;
//echo $product;

$query="SELECT ProductID FROM Products WHERE ProductName = '$product'";

$result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo $row['ProductID'];

//echo $_SESSION['cust'];

//$query="INSERT INTO favourites (CUSTOMER_ID, ProductID) VALUES ('$_SESSION['cust']', '$_SESSION['cust']' )";

$result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ZoomingZoomZoomer. You can use JavaScript or JQuery to send an ajax request to a separate page for example add_to_fav.php which will run the insert query when add to favorite button gets clicked. You can pass the ProductId as an argument and CustomerId can be fetched using session variables.

Comment: Here is an ajax example [simple ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242211/execute-simple-mysqli-query-on-click-with-ajax)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Dharman Thanks. I looked into SQL Injections last night and make some changes to the code to prevent this.